# How to retrieve Request Payload

Tags: php, javascript, json, extjs

I'm using PHP, ExtJS and ajax store.

It sends data (on create, update, destroy) not in POST or GET. In the Chrome Console I see my outgoing params as JSON in the `"Request Payload"` field. `$_POST`  and `$_GET` are empty.

How to retrieve it in PHP?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you are just passing json data through the http body, instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

You can fetch this data with this snippet:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

If you are passing json, then you can do:

```
$data = json_decode($request_body);
```

`$data` then contains the json data is php array.

`php://input` is a so called [wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: the header is application/json

Comment: @AngelinNadar Then this answer applies.

Comment: If using Laravel simply create a helper function that 1. retrieves this string and 2. json_decodes it.  Then it will be no different than an array from Input::all();  On a side not this would probably work for everyone else too.

Comment: You've made my day! I've been struggling with js+php for so long! Thank you very much. Sorry for offtop.

Answer (score 12):

Also you can setup extJs `writer` with [`encode`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-encode)`: true` and it will send data regularly (and, hence, you will be able to retrieve data via  `$_POST` and `$_GET`).

> ... the values will be sent as part of the request parameters as
>   opposed to a raw post (via [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-encode) for encode config of Ext.data.writer.Json)

UPDATE

Also [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-encode) say that:

> The encode option should only be set to true when a root is defined

So, probably, `writer`'s `root` config is required.

Comment: @NikitaKuhta, have you set `writer`'s root config? It may be required. `encode` does work for me http://imageshack.us/f/32/20120308153201.png/