# ExtJs4 Trouble with null JSON server side on store.sync

Tags: php, post, extjs4

here is my store code:

```
 var sql = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'SQL',
    groupField: 'project',
    proxy: {
        type:'ajax',
        api: {                
            read: 'data/showText.php', // Called when reading existing records
            update: 'data/saveRollout.php' // Called when updating existing records                
        },
        actionMethods: {               
            read   : 'GET',
            update : 'POST'               
        },         
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    autoSync: true,
    autoLoad: true
});
```

It sends right json code

```
{
   "projectId":102,
   "project":"2G Rollout and Performance",
   "taskId":123,
   "description":"2)Capacity Sites Delta",
   "january":123,
   "february":0,
   "march":0,
   "april":0,
   "may":0,
   "june":0,
   "july":0,
   "august":0,
   "september":0,
   "october":0,
   "november":0,
   "december":0,
   "id":null
}
```

But there is NULL on response in php file

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST, true));// shows NULL on response
```

Comment: I take we are talking about updates here, as you reads are GET based. Then I'm there's such thing as `$_POST`, there must be some variable in it, so `$_POST['taskId']`. Look at firebug or chrome developer tools for the full request being sent, and if you still can't work it out, please post it.

Comment: In Firebug I can see that store send json on grid update(because of autoSync: true) sending method is POST like you can see in configuration of store. But on ***server side*** $POST array is ***NULL*** How and why it can be?

Comment: I was hoping to see the `Request URL` more than anything. It would show whether or not parameters are not encoded to the url. Anyhow, I replicated your code, so see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually sending your data to the server via the request body, not via the url.

Using:

```
$iRequestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Will work.

See [similar issue and some (additional) excellent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out:

```
writer: {
    type: 'json'
}
```

To see if it handles regular text sent to the server, maybe your server is not handling the JSON encoding well.