# Send json string in ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
var myData = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());

$.ajax({ 
    cache: false,
    url: "http://localhost/Demo/store.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,           
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
            alert(status);              
        }
        else {
            var r = xhr.responseText;                       
        }
    }
});

$decoded = json_decode($_REQUEST['myData'],true);
print_r($_REQUEST);
exit;

if (is_array($decoded))
{
    foreach ($decoded as $value) {
        echo $value["name"] . "=" . $value["value"];
    }
}
```

When i am trying to decode the data in php the error is undefined index myData..Please help me..Thanks.

Comment: Am i using correct format to send the json string..??
In console log its showing the json string like this:
[{"name":"name","value":"xyz"},{"name":"age","value":"22"},{"name":"gender","value":"male"},{"name":"skills","value":"Php"},{"name":"skills","value":"Java"},{"name":"note","value":"sadasd"}]

Comment: please edit your original post with additional information instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: why do you want to JSON.stringify the value, try just with : var myData = $('form').serializeArray();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Request Payload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you pass a string as the `data` property is just appends it as a parameter query string to the URL. If you want to send an encoded JSON string you still need to give it a name:

```
data: {myData: myData}
```

Now you can use the `myData` request parameter in your PHP script.

Comment: I don't expect to get one, but I would rather like an explanation as to what somebody thinks is incorrect about my answer.

Comment: But in json_decode its showing error as json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with:

```
$decoded = json_decode($_POST['myData'],true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this when call ajax

```
data: {'myData' : myData},
```

Then access using

```
json_decode($_POST['myData'],true);
```

or

```
json_decode($_REQUEST['myData'],true);
```

Comment: Even if i declare an object and try to sue it with that i am able but your answer is more of an easy solution easy solution to this..
var param = new Object();
param['myData'] = myData;

Comment: Whne i try to decode json string its showing error as json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Answer (score 0):

try this pass datatype :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/Demo/store.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function(xhr, status) {
    if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
        alert(status);              
    }
    else {
        var r = xhr.responseText;                       
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score -2):

used `dataType:json;`tosend json.

Comment: `dataType` is *The type of data that you're expecting **back** from the server*