# Send with $post parameter in Angulars.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

I try to send a handsontable table data using $http POST with Angulars.js
The code below:

```
 var $container = $("div#table");         
 var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
 $scope.saveData = function() {
                $http.post('save.php', {'data':handsontable.getData()}).success(function(res,status) {
                      if (res.result === 'ok') {
                        console.log('Data saved');
                      }
                      else {
                        console.log('Save error');
                      }
                });
 }
```

But I get a 'Save error' with

```
Undefined index: data in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\save.php
```

I the development tool in Chrome I get Request payload of this form:

```
{"data":[[fdf,gsgg,gsg,null,null,null],[sgsg,sgg,sgg,ggs,null,null]]}
```

I changed parameters in $http.post to get it work but no solution,
Thank you to give some advices!!!

Comment: The request payload isn't correct and is missing a `]`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution in here : [[How to retrieve Request Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload][1])

Instead of retrieving the data in this way

```
$values=$_POST['data'];
```

I fetch in this way:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```